# Is it possible to pass different model type to controller using jquery ajax?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

Let's say I have a Forum model with SubForum property.

View:

```
@model Forum

@using (@Html.BeginForm("DoSomething", "Forum", FormMethod.Post, new { id= "SubForumForm" }))
{
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.subForum.test1)
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.subForum.test2)
     <input id="btn" type="button" value="CLICK" />
}
```

Model:

```
public class Forum
{
     public subForum SubForum { get; set; }
)
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomething(model SubForum)
{
     if (ModelState.isValid)
     {
          //do something with the model
     }
}
```

And I want to pass SubForum property to my controller with jquery ajax :

```
   $('#btn').click(function () {
        if($('#SubForumForm').valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: BASE_URL + "Forum/DoSomething/",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $('#SubForumForm').serializeArray(),
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                },
                success: function (data) {
                },
                error: function (data) {
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

My model SubForm in DoSomething method will always return null, but it works if I change the controller method parameter to :

```
 public ActionResult DoSomething(model Forum)
```

So my question : Is it possible to pass different model type to controller or jquery ajax only works if you pass the exact same model in your View (@model)?

Any help will be appreciated and sorry for bad english.

Comment: try it with $('#SubForumForm').serialize()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Prefix` property of the `[Bind]` attribute

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomething([Bind(Prefix = "subForum")]SubForum model)
```

The reason it does not currently bind is that the posted values are `subForum.test1="SomeValue"`, but since typeof `SubForum` does not contain a property named `subForum`, binding fails. The attribute essentially strips the specified prefix so it becomes `test1="SomeValue"` which will bind because typeof `SubForum` does contain a property named `test1`